filtering an object-array based on another object-array (orderly)
here is my data:
arrayA= [{"studentID":1,"Type":"A"},{"studentID":2,"Type":"B"},{"studentID":3,"Type":"C"},{"studentID":4,"Type":"A"}]
filteredArrayOrderlyOn = [{"studentID":1},{"Type":"A"}] (depending on the order the user selects the filters)

Output should be 
arrayA = [{"studentID":1,"Type":"A"}]

or if the filteredArrayOrderlyOn  array changes because user has control on this selection.
filteredArrayOrderlyOn  = [{"Type":"B"},{"studentID":1}] then output should be nothing []
Or if  
fillteredArrayOrderlyOn  = [{"Type":"A"}] 
then output should be
arrayA= [{"studentID":1,"Type":"A"},{"studentID":4,"Type":"A"}]

So i would like to filter ArrayA, in the correct order, meaning that  in filteredArrayOrderly first the filter should be studentID=1 and then Type which is A.
i have been trying without any luck

newArray = arrayA.filter(function (item) {
    return Object.keys(elem) === Object.keys(item);
  });
})

or using lodash
 newArray = _.filter(arrayA, function (elem) {
  //     return elem.Type=== filteredArrayOrderlyOn.Type ||  elem.studentID=== filteredArrayOrderlyOn.studentID
  //   });

but getting too many repetitions
thakns guys

the order of the filters isn't important, the result would be the same

You can use Array#every() to match any number of keys in the filters:


let arrayA = [
  { "studentID": 1, "Type": "A" },
  { "studentID": 2, "Type": "B" },
  { "studentID": 3, "Type": "C" },
  { "studentID": 4, "Type": "A" }
];

let filteredArrayOrderlyOn = [
  { "studentID": 1 },
  { "Type": "A" }
];

const result = arrayA.filter(item => 
  filteredArrayOrderlyOn.every(filter => Object.keys(filter).every(key => item[key] === filter[key]))
);

console.log(result);




With lodash you can merge the array of filters to a single object (filteredArrayOrderlyOn), and then filter the array of values (arrayA) using _.matches():


const { merge, matches } = _;

const fn = (arr, filters) => arr.filter(matches(merge({}, ...filters)));

const arrayA = [
  { "studentID": 1, "Type": "A" },
  { "studentID": 2, "Type": "B" },
  { "studentID": 3, "Type": "C" },
  { "studentID": 4, "Type": "A" }
];

console.log(fn(arrayA, [{ "studentID": 1 }, { "Type": "A" }]));

console.log(fn(arrayA, [{ "Type": "A" }]));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



